# How display JSF config in view?

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

I'm doing a Web application using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, JSF 2.x (Mojarra), JPA 2 with Hibernate Provider. The application run on Tomcat 7.x.

I have a debug page, I would like to display all the properties of JSF like numberOfViewsInSession, numberOfLogicalViews, facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD, facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS...

I have found for `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE`

```
javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE = #{facesContext.application.projectStage}
```

How to display this informations in a view ?

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about context initializaition parameters as `<context-param>` in `web.xml`, right?

They're available by the implicit `#{initParam}` map in EL which refers under the covers to [`ExternalContext#getInitParameterMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getInitParameterMap%28%29). So, this should do:

```html
<c:forEach items="#{initParam}" var="entry">
    #{entry.key}=#{entry.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Note that `<ui:repeat>` can't be used as it doesn't support `Map`.

Comment: numberOfViewsInSession and numberOfLogicalViews are not display. If they are not present in my web.xml. I suppose the JSF propreties can be accessed ?